# What is Zeppelin charting library

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I tried to find out what is the charting library used by Zeppelin (I assume it is an open source tool) but couldn't figure it out; any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe its [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/index.html), a reusable chart library for [D3](http://d3js.org/).

Answer (score 1):

It's good that Zeppelin has built-in charts. While the function is pretty limited.

Zeppelin has good support for JS. Highcharts is a very powerful JS chart library. There is a small gap between Spark and Highcharts.

[spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts) can be used in Zeppelin, spark-shell, or other spark application.

```
%spark
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts.model._

highcharts(bank
  .series("x" -> "age", "y" -> avg(col("balance")))
  .orderBy(col("age"))).plot()
```

And got a chart [image]